# json4s error: value \\ is not a member of (String, org.json4s.JsonAST.JObject)

Tags: scala, json4s

First of all, I am very new to Scala, so forgive me for eventual stupid mistakes.

In the [Json4s Readme](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) there is the following code:

```
scala> import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
scala> import org.json4s.JsonDSL._


scala> val json =
  ("person" ->
  ("name" -> "Joe") ~
  ("age" -> 35) ~
    ("spouse" ->
    ("person" ->
     ("name" -> "Marilyn") ~
     ("age" -> 33)
    )
  )
)

scala> json \\ "spouse"
res0: org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List(
      (person,JObject(List((name,JString(Marilyn)), (age,JInt(33)))))))
```

I get the following error when I run this code:

```
error: value \\ is not a member of (String, org.json4s.JsonAST.JObject)
json \\ "spouse"
     ^
```

My `sbt` file is the following:

```
name := "Impressions"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1" % "provided",
  //"org.json4s"  %% "json4s-native" % "3.3.0"
  "org.json4s"  %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.3.0"
)
```

and I run the example under `sbt console`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you slightly modify the `json` declaration like this:

```
val json: JObject =
  ("person" ->
  ("name" -> "Joe") ~
  ("age" -> 35) ~
    ("spouse" ->
    ("person" ->
     ("name" -> "Marilyn") ~
     ("age" -> 33)
    )
  )
)
```

...it will work.

I think the compiler assumes you're declaring a tuple with a `String` and a `JObject`, while you actually want to declare a full `JObject`.

Comment: It works! many thanks! but instead of `JObject` I have to use `org.json4s.JsonAST.JObject`. Is there a shortcut for this ugly name?